# Not able to pass data to child react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am pretty new to React, so I am very sorry if my question is dumb, but I'm stuck here. I am trying to send data from parent component to child component

Parent:

```
export default function Dashboard() {

const [msg, setMSG] = useState<string>("Hello!");

  return (

    <Table message={msg}/>
  );

}
```

Child:

```
export default function Orders(message: string) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
{message}
</React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And I am getting an error:

> Type '{ message: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: How are Order and Table related?

Comment: try changing to: `export default function Orders({ message })` if you are passing a `prop` called `message` to `Orders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a type mismatch issue - which means what's being passed down to your child component is an `object`

> `Type '{ message: string; }'`

whereas, your child component has specified its input to be a single `string` by doing this - `Orders(message: string)`

Try the following, that preserves the type-checking:

```
 // now `props` is of type object, 
 // with a `key` called `message`, the value of which is of type `string`
 export default function Orders(props: {message: string}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.message}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass this down as a prop, you have two options, you can destructure the message from the props, or use props.message. I'll show you the destructured way:

```
 export default function Orders({message: string}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {message}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps